# making basic python counter with keyboard input

Tags: python, counter

This probably sounds stupid but I can't seem to make a basic counter. Basically I need it to have two real time inputs, keyboard 'f' for positive points, keyboard 'j' for negative points, then I need one more input 'q' to stop the iteration and then print how many times f and j keys were pressed respectively.

edit: Okay this is frustrating. I searched around more to find out that for real time input I need msvcrt module, I used Windows so no problem. But, it still doesn't do anything, the code just runs and exit, nothing happens.

Here is what I want to do:
1. Run the code.
2. Open up a freestyle video in background.
3. Press the j and f key on the keyboard respectively in real time to count the freestyle score, it's based on clicks, positive points (j) and negative points (f).
4. Video ends, I press q to print how many times I pressed j and f key.

```
import msvcrt    
def counter():
        negative = 0
        positive = 0
        while True:
            score = input("input starts:")
            if msvcrt.getch() == "f":
                negative += 1
                print(negative)
            if msvcrt.getch() == "j":
                positive +=1
                print(positive)
            if msvcrt.getch() == "q":
                print ("positive", positive)
                print ("negative", negative)
                break
```

Comment: `positive==positive+1` -> `positive=positive+1` (comparison vs. assignment). Also, `negative` and `positive` aren't defined outside the `if`s so their values won't persist.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of issue, but here are a few pointers.

Instead of num = num + 1 - use num +=1

Define your counters before incrementing them.

Move your input inside the loop, or else it's going to use the first input over and over and just run through the entire loop with one input.

```
def counter():
        end=1
        negative = 0
        positive = 0
        while end <= 1000:
            end += 1
            score = input("input here:")
            if score == "f":
                negative += 1
                print(negative)
            if score == "j":
                positive +=1
                print(positive)
            if score == "q":
                print ("positive", positive)
                print ("negative", negative)
                break

    counter()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to define `positive` and `negative` outside the `while` loop to keep the changes made to these variables during each iteration. E.g. like so:

```
def counter():
    score = input("input here:")
    end=1
    positive = 0
    ...
```

There's a small typo in `positive==positive+1`. I think you meant `positive=positive+1` (comparison vs. assignment)

Answer (score 0):

The general syntax of your counter is correct though if you want something to be running in the background and are operating outside of the console then you need something like pyHook. getch() wont work in this situation.

```
from pyHook import HookManager
from win32gui import PumpMessages, PostQuitMessage

class Keystroke_Watcher(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.hm = HookManager()
        self.hm.KeyDown = self.on_keyboard_event
        self.hm.HookKeyboard()


    def on_keyboard_event(self, event):
        try:
            if event.KeyID  == keycode_youre_looking_for:
                self.your_method()
        finally:
            return True

    def your_method(self):
        pass

    def shutdown(self):
        PostQuitMessage(0)
        self.hm.UnhookKeyboard()


watcher = Keystroke_Watcher()
PumpMessages()
```

that will detect the keypress and then you can increment the values. Of course you'll need to extrapolate the code but the framework is all there for you to be successful.